# Can't ping “raspberrypi.local” but can use IP address with a Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using WSL on Windows and while I am able to ping and ssh into my Raspberry Pi using its IP address, but I am not able to use `raspberrypi.local`. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B, so `avahi-daemon` is already on it and, according to the Raspberry Pi website and many other places, no setup should be required to access `raspberrypi.local`. I am wondering what I might be doing wrong.

I get the following when I `ping raspberrypi.local`:

> ping: raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known

Comment: apparently mdns/avahi is [possibly broken on](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/384) on WSL. Can you ping it on windows itself?

Comment: Just checked, I am not able to ping it on windows either. Got this message `Ping request could not find host raspberrypi.local. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: Getting sucked down an internet rabbit hole - TIL, windows has super messy, wierdly quirky built in mdns support [this seems to indicate .local addresses could be borked](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/windows-mdns-dnssd.html)

Comment: Okay. It's not that big of an issue; I'll just use the ip address until it is better supported. Thanks anyway! @JourneymanGeek